# Delayed/absent mortarboard badge?

Tags: bug

On Nov 1st I was fortunate enough to earn 215 rep points (which was capped). I have not received a mortarboard badge for this. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mortarboard badge is only awarded one time per user. You already have received this badge on Oct 26th.